# python xml read file

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I hope somebody can help. I am unable to read XML file and have tried many suggested solutions. First of all here is the file:

```
<Program>
 <20180531 />
 <20180601 />
 <20180602 />
 <20180603 />
 <20180604 />
 <20180605 />
 <20180606 />
 <20180607 />
 <20180608 />
 <20180609 />
 <20180610 />
 <20180611 />
 <20180612 />
 <20180613 />
 <20180614 />
 <20180615 />
 <20180616 />
 <20180617 />
 <20180618 />
 <20180619 />
 <20180620 />
 <20180621 />
 <20180622 />
 <20180623 />
 <20180624 />
 <20180625 />
 <20180626 />
 <20180627 />
 <20180628 />
 <20180629 />
 <20180630 />
 <20180701 />
 <20180702 />
 <20180703 />
 <20180704 />
</Program>
```

Just some dates really. This file is generated by calling

```
   import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
   top = etree.Element('Program')
   for day in alldays: # alldays is a list of dates using datetime
       dan = etree.SubElement(top, day.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
       tree = etree.ElementTree(top)
       tree.write(directory + omnifile)
```

But I am unable to read this file by calling:

```
 tree = etree.parse(somefile)
```

I get this error: xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 10

I don't see the problem and cannot understand why a file generated by ElementTree cannot be read by ElemenTree. I am using Python 3.6.5 in Fedora.

Comment: It’s probably because your element names start with a number.

Answer (score 0):

The "XML" file is not well-formed. Element names are not allowed to start with a digit. Note that digits are excluded from the `NameStartChar` production of the XML grammar: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar.

ElementTree is a bit lax when it comes to creating XML output. [lxml](http://lxml.de) on the other hand will not let you do this. If you try, there will be a "Invalid tag name" error.